# Why does a node's position change when a CGFloat is used instead of a numeric literal?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

#### Goal

I want to set the position of a child node in my game's scene using the `position` property of `SKSpriteNode` and pass an inline mathematical expression as the argument to the `y` parameter. The child node I'm adding is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and it has a custom `Int` property called `yOffset`. Ideally, I want to use the `yOffset` to shift the node's position.

#### What I Tried

Initially, I was hard-coding the offset as part of the argument to `CGPoint`, i.e. `myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.position.x, y: myNode.position.y - 100)` and the node was being positioned in the scene as expected.

However, as soon as I changed to using `yOffset`, i.e. `myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.position.x, y: myNode.position.y - myNode.yOffset)` I get a compiler error saying 'Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'CGFloat''. To fix this, I changed `myNode.yOffset` to `CGFloat(myNode.yOffset)` and it compiled fine. However, the node was now nowhere to be found within the scene. The node count still shows that the node was added, but I have no idea where it is.

To avoid a cast to `CGFloat`, I also tried changing `yOffset` to be a `Double` instead of an `Int`. The code compiled fine, but the same problem arose and the node was nowhere to be found.

#### What I want to know

First, why is it that when a numeric literal such as `100` is used in the calculation, the code compiles and the node appears just fine, but when the instance property `yOffset` (which is also an `Int`) is used, it needs to be cast to `CGFloat`? Shouldn't it compile since it is an `Int` just like any numeric literal?

Second, why is it that the node's position does not behave as expected when `yOffset` is cast to `CGFloat`, as compared to using a numeric literal in the argument?

Is it anything to do with a conversion from point to pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGFloat` is, dependent on system architecture, either a `Double` or `Float` under the covers, and standard library floating-point types, such as `Float` and `Double`, conform to the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol. This means you can initialise a variable or constant of any of these types by assigning an integer literal and it will be "translated" to a `CGFloat` by the initialiser associated with the protocol.  When you supply the integer literal in-line as `y: myNode.position.y - 100` this is what is happening.

When you specify the offset property as an `Int` you can't then use this in a calculation that is expecting a `CGFloat` - as it's no longer a literal value the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` initialiser cannot be used to convert it to a `CGFloat`.  Hence you your initial error.

Without seeing the full code, as opposed to inline snippets, it's not clear why you should be getting the placement errors when you offset using the `yOffset` property.  There's no obvious reason.   Have you looked through the code with the debugger to check what is really happening, confirm that the actual property values are what you think they are, and what the position value of the sprite is?

Comment: I see, so because even though the yOffset property is of type Int, since it does not conform to the ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral protocol, it cannot be converted to type CGFloat. Am I getting this right? Also, I took your advice and added breakpoints to print out the myNode object at runtime, and it worked wonders. Turns out I forgot to initialise the yOffset properly before using it. Oops

Comment: Yes, because you actually specify the property as an Int the compiler can't interpret it as a CGFloat by its protocol conformance, and you have to specifically convert it.